# Google Maps Places API, need to get same markers as on Google emded

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-embed

Good day !

I'm developing custom service, that will grab params form Google Maps url, like `https://www.google.nl/maps/search/fietsenmaker/@52.1285737,5.0837216,13z/data=!3m1!4b1?hl=en`. From this example it's possible to take search param, longitude, latitude and zoom level. All this params will pass to Google Places API and markers will be drawn on Google map. The main problem, i can't get this markers look same as on embed Google Maps. Here is attachment:

[image]

In simple words: 
Need to dynamically embed map with listing of places, that was originally in search param and place map center according lat/long with original markers as on embed map.

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: I didn't understand exactly your problem, but you can just don't set map to the marker, no? Or you need a custom marker?

Comment: @BrunoCésar need to dynamically embed map with listing of places, that was originally in search param. Does this make sense ?

Comment: Show your code, a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), maybe makes sense.

Comment: @BrunoCésar You already put minus to this question, but this question is about the way of code architecture and/or documentation of Google Maps.

Comment: The vote down it's not me, even this question deserving it, but ok, sorry for not help you =/

Answer (score 0):

Google Embed API will allow you to embed maps with starting params, like map center, object name. You can find it here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Good luck everybody !